# What happened to ANA 66 on November 12, 2021?

Tags: airport-operations, go-around

Looking by the window I saw two planes approaching Haneda.
It stroke me as a bit odd that one of the plane seemed to have stopped descent and might not have intended to land.

I checked flight radar, and sure enough the flight did not landed and went around.
Then, a cart came and inspected the runaway.

It was at around 16:00 local time and the closure seems to have lasted just a few minutes.

What happened on this runway ?

Comment: See: [When (if ever) can ATC order an aircraft to go around?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/74552/14897) and [How common are cancelled landing attempts?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/8708/14897) / from those: unless there is something worth investigating, it's nothing out of the ordinary and there could be many reasons, which are listed in the first topic

Comment: Probably a report of FOD by a preceding aircraft.

Comment: Not sure how it is "opinion based". Someone with ATC recording could give an answer. We have none right now and that's... fine.

Answer (score 2):

If you noticed an inspection vehicle on the runway in question, some of the possible reason for performing an inspection are:

- previous landed aircraft noticed something on the rwy during landing
- previously landed or departed aircraft was noticed to be missing some parts
- previously landed or departed aircraft reported technical issues during landing or takeoff
- specific to some regions, like Japan, an earthquake of sufficient magnitude was registered near the airport (none were registered within the timeframe you specified)
- animals, drones or other "unauthorized entities" were seen in the vicinity of runway

In addition to these "ad-hoc" inspections there are regularily performed inspection, such as friction measurement if weather deems necessary, but these are scheduled, and should never necessitate go-arounds.